# Virtual machine with Mac OS X

Tags: iphone

I would like to develop an iPhone application, but I do not have a Mac. I would like to find out if it is possible to rent a virtual machine with a Mac OS so that I could develop on that machine. Does anyone offer that service? Would it not make sense because I couldn't connect my phone directly to that machine?

Or perhaps I could rent a Mac.

Or option three is to run Mac OS X in a virtual machine on my Windows laptop. Is that possible?

Comment: Buy a mac. Otherwise you'll be in for a world of headaches.

Comment: Note that it's not legal to run Mac OS X on a virtual machine if the host OS is anything other than Mac OS X.

Comment: If your time is free and infinite, and you'd really rather solve configuration problems than code, try anything but a Mac. Seriously, get yourself a used mini to try it out - it will cost you very little if you lose interest and sell it on. Maybe even profit if you're a good eBay copywriter :-)

Comment: Try a cloud Mac rental service like http://xcodeclub.com - I prefer them since they offer full admin access, got live chat support, and their speeds are the fastest I tried so far. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's certainly possible to run OS X in a VM on Windows - the latest version of [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) is capable of running Snow Leopard.

As the cheapest way of getting into iOS development, I bought an iPod Touch and got VirtualBox up and running. I've now got two apps approved on the App Store. However, once they have made enough money I will be buying a Mac - there is no sound on the VirtualBox VM (although the latest VirtualBox may be capable of producing sound, I haven't managed it yet), I can't map the Mac Control key on the keyboard (so no keyboard shortcuts work) and it's a bit sluggish (on my Core i7 PC with 12GB RAM).

To sum up - the cheapest option is to go for the VM, but you'll probably find yourself wanting a Mac eventually, so it may be easier to just go for the Mac Mini.

Comment: ok, excellent. That is interesting to know that the Virtualbox image can connect to the iOS device via USB. I also got a Virtual box image from a friend which enabled me to play around with xCode and the Mac OS. It works pretty well. But as you suggest, I also just bought a Macbook Air today.

Answer (score 11):

It's probably better to just fork out and buy a [Mac Mini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini), then you can use your existing monitor, mouse and keyboard, and it's pretty OK price wise. Especially since developing an application often means also maintaining it in the future.

Comment: I ended up buying a Macbook Air. It is a beautiful laptop. I run VMWare fusion on it so that I have both Windows and OSX. I also got my mac VirtualBox to run on my Windows laptop, but was not ideal.

Comment: there is no need to choose windows/microsoft, andriod or apple. you can have all!

Answer (score 4):

You can try [macincloud.com](http://www.macincloud.com). $20 something per month for a couple of hours a day, not too bad.

Comment: Based on my experience, Macincloud is the worst solution out there: sluggishly slow, terrible support (good luck!), and no admin rights. Looks like they got hundreds of virtual machines hooked to 1 physical hackintosh. Avoid.

Answer (score 2):

hackintosh or dragonfiresdk (not free)

Answer (score 2):

It's illegal to install Mac OS X on a non-Mac hosted virtual machine. I think you'd get yourself a Mac, remember Mac can install Windows natively ([BootCamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29)). So you are really buying a Windows machine and Mac machine.

If you are ready for getting your hands dirty you could install a Mac operating systems on [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox). VirtualBox doesn't officially support it because it is not legal. Google it, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Not entirely true.  If you have a Mac, you can install a Mac virtual machine but that doesn't really help the OP much :-)

Comment: Per my comment, it's only not legal to run Mac OS X on a VM if the host is not Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

A [Mac Mini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini) is a cheap solution and will let you to develop your apps.

> The current Mac Mini uses a dual-core 64-bit "Penryn" Intel Core 2 Duo processor that runs at 2.4 or 2.66 GHz.

No one is going to recommended you a [hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/).

Comment: Apparently, plan9assembler just did.