# iOS Development on Virtual Box Mac OSX

Tags: ios, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual machine with Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860906/virtual-machine-with-mac-os-x)

I was wondering if anyone has done iOS development on a Virtural Box Mac OS install. I have a macbook pro, but it's older and on the fritz. I was thinking of switching back to a PC laptop to save a little cash. I just want to know if you can create a certificate and use the apploader all from the virtual box image or not? Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything by setting up a Hackintosh using VirtualBox but it is not officially supported and may be illegal to do so.